# SQL Query check result with other rows in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want build SQL query to select row based on date range and also want additional columns
Following is my sample table

```
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | CustomerID   | AccountID    |  DateFrom    |    DateTo    |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | C0001        | A0001        | 21/01/2016   | 28/01/2016   |
|  2 | C0001        | A0001        | 01/02/2016   | 08/02/2016   |
|  3 | C0002        | A0002        | 09/02/2016   | 16/02/2016   |
|  4 | C0002        | A0002        | 14/01/2016   | 21/01/2016   |
|  5 | C0003        | A0003        | 07/01/2016   | 14/01/2016   |
|  6 | C0003        | A0003        | 09/02/2016   | 16/02/2016   |
|  7 | C0004        | A0004        | 01/01/2016   | 07/01/2016   |
|  8 | C0004        | A0004        | 09/03/2016   | 16/03/2016   |
+----+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

If if pass Date Range is from **01/02/2016** to **28/02/2016** then I need result as follows

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| id | CustomerID  | AccountID  |  DateFrom    |  DateTo      |  isPrevious |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | C0001       | A0001      | 01/02/2016   |  08/02/2016  |    Yes      |
|  2 | C0002       | A0002      | 09/02/2016   |  16/02/2016  |    Yes      |
|  3 | C0003       | A0003      | 09/02/2016   |  16/02/2016  |    Yes      |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Explain the logic. What values `isPrevious`?

Comment: check whether same CustomerID & AccoundID  is there any previous date available. if available then Yes else none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This asume you want the data be full contain and no just overlaps with the target range. Also assume none of your row ranges overlap each other.

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 
                  FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.DateFrom < t1.DateFrom
                    and t2.CustomerID  = t1.CustomerID  
                    and t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID ) IS NULL
            THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Yes'
       END as isPrevious

FROM yourTable t1

WHERE DateFrom <= '2016-02-28' and
      DateTo >= '2016-02-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a simple select:

```
select t.*
from t
where DateFrom <= '2016-02-28' and
      DateTo >= '2016-02-01';
```

At least, this would give the results as you describe them.